# How to call my (tiny) mvc methods from HTML (PHP) forms?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, rest, orm

I have the relevant code posted in a gist:

https://gist.github.com/1561520

I was wondering if someone could tell me what the correct way to call the ReportsController->create() method from my form would be. The only idea I can come up with would be to have form have a random action, something like `action="application/views/reports/new.php"` and call my controllers create method from there. The problem is, that defeats the purpose of the `__autoload` function, unless I am mistaken.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was told a 'binding' framework would be how to do this. Anyone have any tips on getting started?

Comment: I have no clue what a "binding" framework is. It looks like you need to find the forms action href for the controller. Create your own "links", convert them when the request comes in and replace them inside the HTML output as the response goes out. Either with some logic you can invoke with functions or by using output buffering (post processing the view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give a simple router like [PHP-router](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router) a try.

```
<?php

require 'Router.php';

$r = new Router();

// maps '/report/create' to controller ReportsController->create().
$r->match('/report/create','ReportsController#create');

if($r->hasRoute()) { ?>

    <h1>Route found!</h1>
    <p><b>Controller: </b><?php echo $r->getRoute()->controller; ?></p>
    <p><b>Action: </b><?php echo $r->getRoute()->action; ?></p>
    <p><b>Params: </b><?php var_dump($r->getRoute()->params); ?></p>

<?php

// Load controller
$controller = new $r->getRoute()->controller;

// Call controller action, and pass params
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $r->getRoute()->action), $r->getRoute()->params);

}
else
{
    die('<h1>No route found.</h1>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A binding framework is nothing but a logic inside your index.php to automatically load the relevant controller, depending on the properties of the HTTP request, especially the URI.

You could mix in RESTful semantics here if you feel like it. So a POST to `/reports` with the data from the form would create the report. GET to `/reports/...` would fetch the report, etc ...

In the past, what I have done is to make use of [$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

So the form would POST to `index.php/reports`, which would give your index.php enough info to make the decision on which Controller instantiate, in order to handle the request. You may encode further options into the URI like `index.php/reports/create`, but that is a little ugly IMO. I personally would prefer RESTful concepts here. So if you are to go for RESTful, you need to inspect $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] and decide which function to call. It would be wise to decide and standardize what you want to name the function that handles each HTTP method, for example Create for POST, Fetch for GET, Remove for DELETE, etc.

Now that we know which controller to load and what the action has to be, you need to let the controller instantiate the Model, followed by the call of relevant function depending on the method ( or the extra params in the PATH_INFO ).

I hope I have given you enough to get you out of the problem at hand.

Comment: This is the direction I have begun to head, and you gave me good insight on the RESTful way. As a rails developer, I truly prefer rest.

Comment: Glad I could help; BTW even though I have done MVC quite a bit ( only due to restrictions / conventions in my company ), I much prefer modelling a RESTful API on top of a Resource concept. IMHO, MVC for simple web applications is over rated! Good luck with your adventure into roll-your-own PHP frameworks; its good fun!